# Saved items sorting order

Tags: sorting

I'm working on a jobs app which allows users to save jobs. Every job on the site has two states, active and ended. When a user saves a job it gets added to their saved area. In this area the user can sort this list of saved jobs in three ways: most recent, oldest or ending soon.

The problem I'm having is how to present the order of jobs when the *ending soon* option is selected. As mentioned before, the jobs on the site can be active or ended. If a user selects *ending soon*, where should I place the ended jobs?

As an aside, I do provide a way for the users to remove any ended jobs from their list, but they can choose not to.

One way I've tried to tackle this is, when the screen loads, the jobs ending soon are in focus, and the ended jobs sit above them, but off screen (see image below).

[image]

Any recommendations or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think sorting the "Ending Soon" jobs in chronological order makes sense.  I would display the "Ended" jobs at the bottom of the list with default sort order of time ended showing the most recent ended jobs first.

Another option is you could add a filter option that shows only "Ended" jobs and not worry about showing the "Ended" jobs in the same list as "ending soon" jobs.